# Can you expand max function like this?

Tags: functions

Is LHS = RHS?

$$
\underset{\pi }{\max}\{\pi (V_m-V_c) + V_c\} = \underset{\pi }{\max}\{\pi (V_m-V_c)\} + V_c?
$$

Edit: all terms are variables but none (besides $ \pi $) are functions of $ \pi $.

Comment: It would improve your Question if you spell out which symbols represent constants and which represent variables.

Comment: The purpose of improving your Question is not to help yourself, but to help your Readers (and not just those who will help you today, but those who may have a similar problem in the future).  Note the Edit link below and to the left of your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming that $V_c$ is not a function of $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks, yes Vc is not a function of pi